# Esp32 Error ESP-Rainmaker - Ivalid MAC Address

Tags: linux, console, iot, esp32

I'm having an issue when trying to use the ESP-Rainmaker CLI for Host Driven Claiming. When I run ./rainmaker.py claim --manufacturer matter --mac xx:xx:xx:xx:xx ttyUSB0 with the corresponding MAC, it shows "Invalid MAC Address." Without the MAC parameter, it says it can't auto-detect it.

I need to know if I'm missing any details or why it's not recognizing that as the MAC.